# Convert multiple objects in array into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arr

I want to convert this:

```
var x = [{ order_id: 10,
           product_id: 5,
           product_after_price: 50 },
         { order_id: 10,
           product_id: 6,
           product_after_price: 50 }]
```

Into this:

```
[[10, 5, 50], [10, 6, 50]]
```

I tried .map() function but it just doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Ordering of keys in the object is not guaranteed, not sure if you will get a straightfoward answer.

Comment: try `arr.map( s => Object.values(s) )`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Ya this worked, thanks. I don't get why people directly attack me with "-1"s, I'm a beginner and I'm here to learn stuff. Smh.

Comment: Did you checked the answers shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without considering order, simply use `map`

```
arr.map( s => Object.values(s) )
```

**But you need to specify the order first**

```
var order = ["order_id", "product_id", "product_after_price"];
```

then use `map`

```
var output = arr.map( function(item){
   return order.reduce( function(a,c){
      a.push( item[c] );
     return a;
   }, []);
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var order = ["order_id", "product_id", "product_after_price"];
var x = [{
    order_id: 10,
    product_id: 5,
    product_after_price: 50
  },
  {
    order_id: 10,
    product_id: 6,
    product_after_price: 50
  }
];
var output = x.map(function(item) {
  return order.reduce(function(a, c) {
    a.push( item[c] );
    return a;
  }, []);
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the order of the values in the array across different JS engines, you can create an array of property keys (`order`), and iterate it to get the values in the requested order.

```js
const order = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'product_after_price'];

const x = [{"order_id":10,"product_id":5,"product_after_price":50},{"order_id":10,"product_id":6,"product_after_price":50}];
           
const result = x.map((o) => order.map((key) => o[key]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really the very simple question, it is my kind advice that you should refer javascript core functions first before post a question here.

```js
var x = [{ order_id: 10,
           product_id: 5,
           product_after_price: 50 },
         { order_id: 10,
           product_id: 6,
           product_after_price: 50 }]
        
var arrValues = []
for(var index=0; index< x.length; index++){
 if(!!x[index]){
   arrValues.push(Object.values(x[index]));
  }
}
console.log(arrValues);
```